# Counting distinct rows in MySQL and group the result while omitting dupes and null result

Tags: database

I am trying to query the database but i need help getting it right. Have two issues.

Database is for hamradio contesting and booth querys applies on the same table.

Table "LOG" with columns: MCall, SCall, sm, mm, conf
where MCall and SCall is unique per user but exists in multiple rows
sm and mm is an idenifier number for areas
conf 1 or 0 depending on if the data is valid or not

LOG containing

```
MCall   SCall   sm    mm    Conf
SM6ASD  ADMIN   2422  2462  1   
SM6ASD  ADMIN   2422        0
ADMIN   SM5QWE  2321        0
ADMIN   SM1ZXC  1766        1
SM6ASD  ADMIN   1860        1
SM6ASD  SM6ABC  2584  2510  1
SM6ASD  SM6ABC  2161        1
SM6ASD  SM6ABC  1785        1
SM6ASD  ADMIN   0114        1
SM6ASD  ADMIN   1230  1496  1
SM6ASD  ADMIN   1230  1230  1
```

Issue 1

Calculate a score for each MCall.
Score calculated by this:

```
A row with "Conf" = 0 gives 0 points
A row with "Conf" = 1 and "sm" set gives 1 point
A row with "Conf" = 1 and "mm" set gives 1 point
A row with "Conf" = 1 and "sm" or "mm" set gives 2 points
A row with "Conf" = 1 and "sm" = "mm" set gives 1 point
```

Eg
1:st row SM6ASD gives a score of 2 points
2:nd row SM6ASD gives a score of 0 points
Last row SM6ASD gives a score of 1 points

This query will count 2 points for sm != mm. How can i omit that?

```
SELECT distinct MCall, sm, mm, SUM(IF(sm != '', 1,0)) + SUM(IF(mm != '', 1,0)) AS 'points' 
FROM LOG WHERE conf = '1' GROUP BY `MCall` ORDER BY `points` DESC
```

Issue 2
Need to count distinct occurrence of "sm" and "mm" per user (MCall)
The result shall be a descending list of unique identifiers from "sm" and "mm"

Scoring should be:
SM6ASD 10 areas (distinct)
ADMIN 1 area

Have tried many querys but none good enough
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sm, mm) AS `areas`, `MCall` FROM `LOG` WHERE conf = "1" GROUP BY MCall

returns a wrong amount. I think the query counts one NULL occurence!?

```
SELECT sm 
FROM LOG 
UNION 
SELECT mm 
FROM LOG 
WHERE MCall = "SM6ASD" AND conf = "1"
```

will list the right answer but how can I count the rows instead, and at the same time group the result per user

eg

```
SM6ASD 10 areas
ADMIN 1 areas
```

Hoping for some help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mycall, count(conf) 
FROM KJ_log 
WHERE ((sm != mm) OR (sm IS NOT NULL AND mm IS NOT NULL) OR (mm IS NOT NULL AND sm IS NOT NULL)) and conf = "1" 
GROUP BY mycall
```

I'm The best :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Issue 2 solved by..

```
SELECT distinct mycall, sm, mm, SUM(IF(sm = mm, 1,0)) + SUM(IF(sm != mm, 0,0)) + SUM(IF((sm != mm) AND (sm = ''), 1,0)) + SUM(IF((sm != mm) AND (mm = ''), 1,0)) + SUM(IF((sm != mm) AND (mm != '') AND (sm != ''), 2,0)) AS 'points'
FROM KJ_log WHERE conf = '1'
GROUP BY `mycall`
ORDER BY `points` DESC
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).